# Omnet++ (Castalia)

Tags: omnet++

There is available castalia master file at github. But I want **castalia 3.2** can anyone suggest me, from where I find this.

Comment: Please format your question to be readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all versions of Castalia from the github repository.

https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/releases

As always, it is recommended that you use the latest version of Castalia (found in github). Not only it contains more features, but it fixes several bugs of older versions. Look at the [CHANGES.TXT](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/blob/master/Castalia/CHANGES.txt) file to see the main bug fixes and extra features version 3.3 offers. You can also look at the [commit history](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/commits/master) to find out about the (limited) changes since 3.3 was released.